# Looking for a Menu Module on Node Page

Tags: 8, navigation

Out site has many, many nodes included in a number of menus. When creating a node, the Parent Item select box under Menu Settings is quite long.

Is there a module that provides a better, more usable interface to selecting the parent item? I've done some searching and couldn't find anything.

Comment: You could set the fixed parent on the content type, I believe.

Comment: also you could give https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen ago

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you [Menu Link Weight](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_weight) together with [Client-side hierarchical select](https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs). The combination of those two modules allow you to separate each level in an own select field and makes sorting pages within a level very handy.

After installing both of them visit `/admin/config/user-interface/menu-link-weight` and select "**Client-Side hierarchical select**".

This solution works very well for a site where we use a lot of levels and menu items.